# Prove $-4\sin^4⁡(\frac{1}{2}x) =-4 \sin^2⁡(\frac{1}{2} x)+\sin^2x$

Tags: trigonometry

I want to prove :

$$-4\sin^4⁡(\frac{x}{2}) =-4 \sin^2⁡(\frac{x}{2} )+\sin^2x$$

I try to factoring :
$$-4 \sin^2⁡(\frac{x}{2} )+\sin^2x = (\sin x+2\sin(\frac{x}{2} ))(\sin x-2\sin(\frac{x}{2} ))$$ but I can't simplify it to left hand side.

What should first I do to prove it? Any hint to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider, right hand side
$$\begin{aligned}
-4\sin^2{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}+\sin^2{x}&=-4\sin^2{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}+\left(2\sin{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\cos{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\right)^2\\
&=-4\sin^2{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}+4\sin^2{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\cos^2{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\\
&=-4\sin^2{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\left(
1-\cos^2{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\right)\\
&=-4\sin^2{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\sin^2{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\\
&=-4\sin^4{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\sin(x) = 2\sin(\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{x}{2})$$

Answer (score 1):

**Another hint:**

You could also try squaring
$$
\cos x=\Big(1-2\sin^2\big(\frac{x}{2}\big)\Big)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint.
$4\sin^2x/2-4\sin^4x/2=4\sin^2x/2(1-\sin^2x/2)=4\sin^2x/2\cos^2x/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\sin\left(\frac 12x\right)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}{2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

We wish to show $$\sin^2 x-\frac 14\sin^2(2x)=\sin^4 x.$$

Since $\sin(2x)=2\sin x\cos x$, the LHS equals $\sin^2 x-\sin^2 x\cos^2 x$, that is, $\sin^2 x(1-\cos^2 x)$. Can you finish from here?